# C# Api Removing Objects

Tags: c#, json, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm having some issues with my WebAPI.

I Have the following models.

ModelA

```
Guid id;
String name;
Guid ModelBId;
virtual ModelB ModelB;
```

ModelB

```
Guid id;
String name;
```

I'm creating a list with 2 instances of ModelA, each instance has a name and have the same reference to modelB, exemple:

```
obj1 = New ModelA("myName", "1edh-...");
obj2 = New ModelA("otherName", "1edh-...");
```

Both objects references the same ModelB object, so, I Include the two on a list.

```
List<ModelA> myList = new List<ModelA>();
myList.Add(obj1);
myList.Add(obj2);
```

Now, if I look at "myList" at debugger I can see the both references to ModelB, but when my controller returns it to my client, one of them disappears.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var myList = _uow.functionality.Get(id);
            //myList contains two objects, just like the example
            return Ok(myList );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The Json that returns to my user is the following

```
   [
  {$id: 1, 
    id: 'ed32-...', 
    name: 'myName', 
    ModelB: { $id: 2, 
              $ref: 1, 
              id: '', 
              name: ''}}, 
  {$id: 3, 
    id: 'e3df-...', 
    name: 'otherName', 
    ModelB: { $ref: 2 }}
]
```

Why does it remove my ModelB from the json on sending it to my client ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand.  It looks like `ModelB` is still there in the resulting json.

Comment: @SamIam Yes, ModelB is returning on the first relation, but it is excluded from the second relation and replaced with a $ref to the $id of the first relation

Comment: Web API uses [tag:json.net].  Somewhere you must have enabled [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm).  This setting enables serialization of many-to-many references between objects in a graph by labeling each object with an `$id` property the first time it is encountered in the graph, then serializing just a `$ref` property for subsequent references.

Comment: @dbc

formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

Tried to set to .None, doesn't affect the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @dbc suggestion, I've changed the json serialization from

```
formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

To

```
formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does reverting the order shed any light ? Perhaps try returning the list in a different format e.g. a straight JSON object.